# Creating a function to update the first null value in the specified column with the new value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I have this table named 'Details' with 4 columns.

| name | age | occupation | birth_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jav | 25 | null | 1997 |
| david | null | null | 2000 |

The requirement is if I insert a value in occupation column, I want this to insert on the first null row. Which means, I want the null rows of the column to be filled first.
For example,

```
insert into details(occupation)
values('student');
```

I want to create a function which will return the result like this if I just insert any new value

| name | age | occupation | birth_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jav | 25 | **student** | 1997 |
| david | null | null | 2000 |

My question is, how to update the values of a column in a single query if the value is null then update with the new value.

I've come with these two function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_null_value(value int)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE details
    SET occupation = value
    WHERE occupation IS NULL
    RETURNING occupation
    INTO value;

    SELECT value
    FROM details
    WHERE occupation= value
    LIMIT 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Whenver I pass a value, I get this error.
ERROR:  query returned more than one row
HINT:  Make sure the query returns a single row, or use LIMIT 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_null_value(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: P0003

If I limit 1 in the update, like this function. I get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "limit" as we cant use limit 1 in update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_null_value(value int)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO organization_map (organization_id)
    VALUES (value);

    UPDATE organization_map
    SET organization_id = value
    WHERE organization_id IS NULL
    limit 1
    RETURNING organization_id
    INTO value;

    SELECT value
    FROM organization_map
    WHERE organization_id = value
    order by organization_id
    LIMIT 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to create a function the works for all the columns and rows.
Please help.

Comment: If name is unique in that table, then select name where occupation is null LIMIT 1, first, then next call the update statement with WHERE condition name equal to the name obtained in first step.

Comment: "the first null row", what is your definition of "first" ? Your update statement updates all records where occupation IS NULL, not a specific one. If you want to update just one record, you have to tell the database what record that should be

Comment: 'First' makes no sense at all without `order by`

Comment: This whole process is nonsensical, starting with: 'The requirement is if I insert a value in occupation column, I want this to insert on the first null row.' You can't insert into an existing row, you can update an existing row. Then there is the previously mentioned first row problem where first is an arbitrary value unless you use order by. Overall it has the earmarks of a poor design.

Comment: I want to search the 'first null value' of the specified column and then update the value with the new value passed through the function. @FrankHeikens

Answer (score 0):

this function should work ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_null_value(value int)
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS $$
    UPDATE details
    SET occupation = value
    WHERE occupation IS NULL
    RETURNING occupation :: text ; 
$$ ;
```

but it will return the input parameter `value` which is already known, and it will update all the rows where `occupation IS NULL` !

As stated by @Frank & @Stefanov : how do you identify the 'first' and only row to be updated ? You need here an additional condition or a sorting to select only one row.